# Constraint self referencing foreign key to limit nesting (SQL, Sequelize)

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to make a table for example which consists of this structure:

```
<Comments>
id(PK, int)    comment_id(FK, int)    body(text)
1              null                   "This is a comment"
2              1                      "This is a nested comment"
3              2                      "This is a nested nested comment"
```

The above example represents the advantages of using self referencing tables - which I want to eliminate at a certain level.

The `id: 3` of the comment is referencing to `comment_id=2` comment while `id=2` is referencing `comment_id=1`.

I want to limit this nested-referencing to a single level with the ability to add a specific constraint which checks and establishes a value equal to the first level of nest.

To make it more clear, the `id=3` at this point instead of referencing `comment_id=2` should reference the `comment_id=1` and look like this:

```
<Comments>
id(PK, int)    comment_id(FK, int)    body(text)
1              null                   "This is a comment"
2              1                      "This is a nested comment"
3              1                      "This is a nested nested comment"
```

I want to keep the back-end as less busy as possible in handling such situations and just by providing a reference of `comment_id=2` in my create query I would like it to automatically point it to `id=2`'s reference of `comment_id=1` instead of `comment_id=2`

Apart from me using Sequelize in NodeJS and being able to constraint the data in the  back-end routes, I would like to understand how would this be possible to achieve with sql (or sequelize) to keep the data integrity flow linear.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by having another table.  If you comments are referencing *something*, then you can use that table.  Otherwise:

```
create table comments (
    commentId int primary key,
    . . .
);

create table commentLines (
    commentLineId int primary key,
    commentId int references comments(commentId),
    comment varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: This does seem logical and I have thought about this solution, but is it the only way of achieving this? As I would like to keep the idea of self-referencing table.

Comment: @moodseller . . . I think this does a better job of expressing the data model that you want to express.